# Need help in migrating communities from Sandbox to production

Tags: community, deployment, change-set, partner-communities

While trying to deploy my community, I have been facing this error :

"The page "/PartnerIncentiveClaim" for Menu Item "New Incentive Claim" must be published, begin with a / character, and consists only of characters that are permitted in a URL path for Menu Item Type "Internal"

Although my page is already published. Can anyone please help in identifying what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue. It took a long time to figure out since the error message we see ins't the actual error.

In my case,

1. I created list view on Opportunity object.
2. Used it in a lightning component by referencing its API name.
3. Used the lightning component in a community page.
4. Referenced the community page in partner portal navigation menu.

I forgot to include the list view I created in step 1. But Salesforce threw error about the navigation menu URL path which is actually correct. It would have been helpful if it threw a error about the lightning component which is referencing the missing component.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this issue erroneously and it's been resolved with the steps below. May help somebody:

- In the source sandbox, in Community Administration, rename the community to be something completely different to what it is now
- In the source sandbox, in Community Administration, rename the community to be the proper/desired name again
- In the destination sandbox, create a brand new Lightning community with any name, as long as it’s not the name you want to use
- In the destination sandbox, in Community Administration, rename this community to have the proper name
- Attempt the deployment again

This of course assumes that the there isn't some other issue with the deployments contents.

Answer (score -1):

We ran in the same problem. We have some components added on the page which is being called on navigation menu click, but those are part of our deployment. Still, no luck.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/197400)