# Migrating a communities from Sandbox to PartialCopy

Tags: community, deployment, sandbox, change-set, partner-communities

I'm trying to deploy a Partner community from a sandbox to a partial-copy, but I receive this error:

> The page "/event" for Menu Item "Event" must be published, begin with
>   a / character, and consists only of characters that are permitted in a
>   URL path for Menu Item Type "Internal".

Beyond my specific case with the event page, do you have any suggestion?

- "/" character is put in the url by default
- This community is published.

Question related to([Need help in migrating communities from Sandbox to production](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211749/need-help-in-migrating-communities-from-sandbox-to-production)) .

I know this is a duplicated question but due to the min reputation value requested I'm not able to comment the previous one and al my reply have been delated by the moderator.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue. It took a long time to figure out since the error message we see ins't the actual error.

In my case,

1. I created list view on Opportunity object.
2. Used it in a lightning component by referencing its API name.
3. Used the lightning component in a community page.
4. Referenced the community page in partner portal navigation menu.

I forgot to include the list view I created in step 1. But Salesforce threw error about the navigation menu URL path which is actually correct. It would have been helpful if it threw a error about the lightning component which is referencing the missing component.

Comment: I put this task on hold, as soon as I resume I'll let you know

Comment: Did you ever solve this?